# Why is the return type of CString::GetLength() int and not size_t

Tags: mfc

I wonder why the return type of the `CString::GetLength()` method is `int` and not `size_t`, especially if the return type of `strlen` *is* `size_t`.

Could it be because of compatibility with old MFC versions?

Comment: `CString::GetLength()` was there (ca. 1992), before there was a `size_t` in C++ (or C++ for that matter).

Comment: @IInspectable if you post this as an answer, I'll accept it.